# What Pex system and re-design would you use for this small bungalow update - Floor Plans Attached?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, design, pex, basement-refinishing

There is a small Bungalow in the Midwest that I have attached two new design drawings for.  Its a smaller 740sqft home with a 1st floor and current unfinished basement.  I wanted to see if the group had any opinions on how they would plumb the basement/upstairs based on the new drawings in pex.  I have read a little bit about Truck/Branch design, Home-Run Manifold, and Submanifold systems.

Currently the entire house is demo'd down to the studs, included ceilings, so it's a wide open box on both levels.  The basement is unfinished with an 8" poured foundation.  Home is wood framed with aluminum siding.  Most of the work will be in the basement.  Space will be divided into two halves.  North side will be two bedrooms with proper egress and two small bathrooms close to one another.  The lower half will be some extra living space to the left and the right side will be the new space for the washer/dryer, utility sink, and a pet washing station (a laundry wall).  The plan is to replace the current water heater with a gas tankless version.

So if any of you that have an opinion from looking at these drawings....that would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks a ton in advance - JP 
[image: New Basement Floor Plan]
[image: New Upstairs Floor Plan]

Comment: Proposing edits to remove a lot of the personal details. We really don't need to know those (in most cases) and personal privacy is certainly important.

Comment: If the copper is in good shape and runs where it needs to be, why would you change to PEX?

Comment: Hari - Sorry for too much detail.  That's just the way I am.  I edited the post to just include what I hope would be an overall idea of the plan plus the two drawings.   Thanks.

Comment: Tyson - I understand your point.  I was asking the question because 90% of the copper lines aren't where they need to be with the new design.  So its either cut and re-use this copper as best as we can, or I guess I was contemplating whether the "start from scratch" method may even save some time and effort in the end.   The current layout may have worked in the previous floor plan, but things are going to be much different now and was just trying to weigh all options.

Comment: @J.P if you actually want people to find your comment replies you should use an @ sign in front of the name.  They will be notified to re-visit this question, otherwise they may not see your reply.  You can also edit your question to add new information that was omitted, editing the question brings renewed attention by the entire community.  Please visit the help center and take the tour.